# Structuring content inside Knowledge

Tags: knowledge, hierarchy

After a product demo with the Salesforce crew and also some poking around other companies’ help sites I’m coming to the conclusion that it’s difficult to publish content (or Articles) in a hierarchy. I'm still not 100% if I'm right or not.

**My questions:**

1. Is my assumption correct?
2. If it is possible, what level of customization is needed to impose hierarchy on content in Knowledge.

**What we are trying to do**

We want the Tech Writer to be able to manage hierarchy easily within the Knowledge admin section ending up with a structure like this:

·         *Support/our-product-1/topic/content-item-1*

·         *Support/our-product-1/topic/content-item-2*

Where *our-product-1* uses a product overview type template

*Topic* uses a product topic type template

*Content item* uses a specific Article template (depending on what type of article it is. Eg. Content-item-1 is an FAQ Article type, Content-item- 2 is an instructional piece Article type)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

support.activision.com/

This site is on force.com and uses knowledge base.You can browse through each article to see how they are organised.

The requirement can be achieved since knowledge articles support html.With html content you can organise.

For having different template based on article type you can use articles inside visualforce.So depending on article type you can decide which template to render.This requires little customization.but requirement looks doable .

There is an appexchange product PKB.This is an unmanaged package but the code can be customized .This app will be of real help.